# Unicode non-breaking space is removed end of label

Tags: ios, uitableview, unicode, swift3

I'm using tableview and i use one cell to create many columns.My column number is not fixed so i had to create columns using for loop inside cellForRowAt function.I want to give some spaces between my labels inside my cell.This piece of code succesfully inserts non-breaking spaces to head of the label but it removes end of the label.Thanks for your help.

```
        let spaces = String(repeating:"\u{00A0}",count : columnSpaceCount)
        if globalSubviewHeaderStructArray[i].type == "numeric"{
            if globalSubviewHeaderStructArray[i].digitsAfterComma != "0" {
                var dataNumber = applyComma(comma : globalSubviewHeaderStructArray[i].digitsAfterComma , data : globalSubviewDataArray[indexPath.row][i])
                var newString = "\(spaces)\(checkCurrency(option: globalSubviewHeaderStructArray[i].currency, data: dataNumber))\(spaces)"
                newLabel.text = newString
            }else{
                var newString = "\(spaces)\(checkCurrency(option: globalSubviewHeaderStructArray[i].currency, data: globalSubviewDataArray[indexPath.row][i]))\(spaces)"
                newLabel.text = newString
            }
        }else{
            var newString = "\(spaces)\(checkCurrency(option: globalSubviewHeaderStructArray[i].currency, data: globalSubviewDataArray[indexPath.row][i]))\(spaces)"
            newLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
            newLabel.text = newString
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need space at the end of the label text?

Comment: user has ability to change the view of the labels,for example he can change the alignment or font or colors.Think about two labels left one is aligned to the right and right one is aligned to the left so it looks two data is combined.btw column width is exactly lenght of data so i cant wide my column width.

Comment: Wen you edit a Word document do you use the space bar for alignment there too? Or do you update the margin sizes etc... Don't do it here. Put margins around the label to fix alignment etc... Like @matt said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to give some spaces between my labels inside my cell

Don't do this by messing with the content of the label. Do it by messing with the position / size of the labels themselves. Insert actual *space* (that is, empty pixels) between the *labels*.

Answer (score 0):

To insert space in between `UILabels` within a `UITableViewCell`, set up Autolayout `Contraints`, either in `Storyboard` or in code. Depending on the target iOS version, embedding the `UILabels` in a `StackView` is probably the easiest way, but it's available in iOS >= 8 only.

Select the labels:

[image]

Choose `Embed in` -> `Stack View`:

[image]

Set spacing:

[image]

Also set the contraints for the `StackView` to your needs:

[image]